# make phone call working in mobile but not in desktop

Tags: html

I tried using href="tel:911" this works perfectly fine with mobile phone and I tried using windows 10 with google chrome, it works! But with windows 7, using google chrome with the updated version the code doesn't work.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow - if you could please provide your full code that would be much appreciated, as we cannot fully tell what could be causing this issue from your current summary.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code basically is as simple as this: Toll Free<a class="phone_number" href="tel:911">Emergency Call</a>

Answer (score 0):

this is browser settings specific, ie. it will behave differently depending on the user's browser settings. The user can change how `mailto:` or `tel:` links behave in chrome by visiting `chrome://settings/handlers`, or `Chrome Settings->Content Settings->Manage Handlers...`

check chrome docs: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/click-to-call/